# Why does bash find command not return files in /home/*/.local/share/Trash/files?

Tags: find

I'm trying to empty all the Trash bin files located in `/nfshome/*/.local/share/Trash/files`

But I can't seem to find the proper `find` command to do it:

I can find files and dirs within the Trash directory:

```
$ sudo find /nfshome/*/.local/share/Trash/
/nfshome/9916091/.local/share/Trash/
/nfshome/9916091/.local/share/Trash/files
/nfshome/9916091/.local/share/Trash/info
/nfshome/9918452/.local/share/Trash/
/nfshome/9918452/.local/share/Trash/expunged
/nfshome/9918452/.local/share/Trash/files
/nfshome/9918452/.local/share/Trash/files/mods.2
... plus lots more
```

But I don't get what I would expect if I drill down one more into the `files` directory:

```
$ sudo find /nfshome/*/.local/share/Trash/files/
/nfshome/admin/.local/share/Trash/files/
```

Only one result.  The result happens to be the user I am currently logged in with.  Why doesn't it find the rest of the traash files?  FOr example, these two from the first search?

```
/nfshome/9918452/.local/share/Trash/files
/nfshome/9918452/.local/share/Trash/files/mods.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your shell who expands `*` before `find` starts. The shell runs without `sudo`. To match many `/nfshome/*/.local/share/Trash/` it needs to access many `share` directories. It apparently can, in the first case it works.

But to match many `/nfshome/*/.local/share/Trash/files/` the shell needs to access many `Trash` directories. Hypothesis: the shell is permitted only to access one `Trash`. It has no permission to know there are `files/` in other `Trash` directories.

In the first case `find` got many `Trash` directories and descended having all the permissions because of `sudo`; so it could find all `files/`. In the second case `find` got just one directory named `files/` as an argument.

We could test if it's about not having read permission, execute permission or both. These details cannot change my main point: your shell is not permitted to "detect" some directories, `sudo find …` is permitted to find them all.

Comment: Can you give an example how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

As @KamilMaciorowski says

## Solutions:

### run a `bash` as root.

`sudo bash -c 'find /nfshome/*/.local/share/Trash/'`

### Do it in `find`

Tell find the base directories, and use `-path` etc.

E.g. (not quite right, as it will find `.local` in any sub-directory)

```
sudo find /home -path "*/.local/share/Trash/*"
```

Better.
Convert to a regex (to do the same as the one above).

```
sudo find /home -regex ".*/[.]local/share/Trash/.*"
```

Then anchor to a home directory

```
sudo find /home -regex "/home/[^/]+/[.]local/share/Trash/.*"
```

Comment: can you provide an explicit example using `-path`?  does that replace `-name`?

Comment: `sudo 'bash -c find /nfshome/*/.local/share/Trash/'` => `command not found`; all your other three in `find` work, thank you.

Comment: Sorry the quote got put in the wrong place (fixed).